# HDD Free Space is Inconsistent

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I suspect something strange about my disk usage. I had 9GB of free space on my primary partition and then after two days suddenly I had 16GB free. I had not since installed, deleted, or downloaded anything. This has repeated several times; free space on my primary partition (C:) seems to rise and fall by itself. Can someone explain where this might be coming from? I am using Windows 7 x64.

Comment: run a chkdsk /r on the OS partition, this will sort out any free space issues in the file system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much a problem but could be being caused by [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) creating new restore points and deleting old restore points.

The creation of a restore point is done automatically every few days, I would expect the check for and deletion of old restore points to happen on a similar time frame.

Creating a restore point would block off some space while deletion would free it up again.

Restore points (also known as shadow copies) allow you to use [Previous Versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions), which is a useful feature if you accidentally delete a file, and also allow you to restore your system to a previous "known good" working state.